# Handling DataGrid Update Events

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

In my `CustomerCollectionViewModel`, I have a `ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel>` `CustomerList` and a property called `CurrentCount` property that returns `CustomerList.Count()`.

In the associate view, the I bind CustomerList to a DataGrid and CurrentCount to a label. In reality their are many other dependent properties that present aggregate information about the the CustomerList. About a dozen or so.

My current understanding of MVVM would require bloating the `CustomerViewModel` with `SendPropertyChanged()` for all the aggregate summery labels in UI. Isn't it possible to all `CustomerViewModel` update events that bubble out of the `DataGrid` be caught and then fan out to update the aggregate labels.

Comment: Can you show some code to highlight what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

I bound the lost focus event of a textbox style to a command in the immediate viewmodel's data context.  This command takes the textbox name as the parameter.  This was achieved through using MVVM-Light's relay command, but there are other ways of doing this.

Then in my viewmodel I have a LostFocusCommand that I use to "refresh" my aggregate values and notify the UI of the changes.

All I have to to is apply the text box style to the textboxes i want to trigger this command event (i have a style for comboboxes etc. that binds to the same command, so It does not just have to be text boxes.).

One place to maintain code and you can evaluate the textbox name to take more specific or isolated actions.

Hope this helps.  can't be more specific without seeing code or knowing what framework your using.